# Methods inside ref variables are undefined while testing

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing a test case for a method in which one of my ref variable `AlertPro.open()` is getting called.

When I run the test case I am getting the below error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

```js
openConfirmationDialog = () => {
    this.AlertPro.open(); //here the error is showing
}
```

My Code :

```js
<AlertPro
    ref={ref => {
        this.AlertPro = ref;
    }}
    title="Delete Confirmation"
    message="Do you want to Delete ?"
    textCancel="Cancel"
    textConfirm="Delete"
    onConfirm={() => 
    this.deleteTimeEntry(this.state.deletedObject)}
    onCancel={() => this.AlertPro.close()}
    customStyles={{

        mask: {
            backgroundColor: "transparent"
        },
        container: {
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: "#E6E6E6",
            width: 300,
        },
        buttonCancel: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.dark_brown

        },
        buttonConfirm: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.dark_brown
        }
    }}
/>
```

There is no conditional rendering for this element.

My Testcase :

```js
    test("open Confirmation dialog",() => {

          const appData = shallow(<TimeEntryPage />)

          const component = shallow(<TimeEntryPage />)
          const instance = component.instance()
          instance.openConfirmationDialog({});

    })
```

Do I need to pass ref params to the testing component. If yes how can I pass the Alertpro.

I have tried the below code also but getting same error.

```js
  const component = shallow(<TimeEntryPage />)
      const instance = component.instance()

      instance.refs = {
            AlertPro: {
          getRenderedComponent: jest.fn(() => ({
            open: jest.fn
          }))
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you try doing      `if( this.AlertProp) this.AlertPro.open();`

Comment: Hi Auticcat
Thats working if i put if condition but the Alert is not opened.I want to test whether it is opening or not.Is it possible.

Comment: When do you call the function? can't find it in the code

Comment: In my testcase

test("open Confirmation dialog",()=>{

      const appData = shallow(<TimeEntryPage />)

      const component = shallow(<TimeEntryPage />)
      const instance = component.instance()
//Here
       instance.openConfirmationDialog({});

})